# PHP shared extensions installation issue

Tags: php, installation, freebsd

I have an issue when installing php from sources on FreeBSD 10.2

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php53 \
--without-pear \
-with-pcre-regex=/usr/local \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local \
--enable-shared=yes \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp=shared \
--enable-mbstring=shared \
--enable-soap=shared \
--enable-sockets=shared \
--enable-zip=shared \
--with-zlib \
--with-curl=shared \
--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
--enable-dba \
--with-gd=shared \
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--with-iconv=/usr/local \
--with-gnu-ld \
--with-layout=GNU
```

PHP works fine. But in extensions directory I get:

```
libcurl.a
libftp.a
libgd.a
libmbstring.a
libsoap.a
libsockets.a
libzip.a
```

There are no '.so' files. And I can't load extensions manually in `php.ini`.
Also I tried to install some extensions by pecl and get same result.
Where did a made a mistake? How to build PHP with '.so' extensions?

Comment: Can upload your config.log somwhere

Comment: config.log: http://pastebin.com/2LMCRXNv

Comment: Thats. not config.log, that is the output of configure, Here is the culprit:  checking if libtool supports shared libraries... no
checking whether to build shared libraries... no

Answer (score 1):

Issue is related to "configure" script.  It checks for various versions of FreeBSD, like freebsd3*, freebsd2* and freebsd1*.  When running this on freebsd10.0+, the script thinks it's freebsd1.0, which disables shared objects and dynamic linking.  Removing the offending freebsd1* lines from the configuration fixes this issue.
More information - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66007